# Logging multiple serial ports to multiple files simultaneously

Tags: c#

I am writing a C# program that will read data from multiple serial port simultaneously and log that data to file. Each port will have it's own dedicated file to write to.

I was able to successfully create a class to do this with one port, however when I attempt to do it with two ports only the port that is opened second has any data written to the file.

Below is the class I have written to handle the data received events from the serial port and write to the files:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Shell
{
    public class Shell
    {
        private string port_name;

        static SerialPort port;
        static FileStream fs;
        static StreamWriter stream;

        /*------------------------------------------------------
        Constructors can be added as needed to take
        additional inputs for more flexibility.
        ------------------------------------------------------*/
        public Shell(string name)
        {
            port = new SerialPort();

            port_name = name;

            port.PortName = name;
            port.BaudRate = 115200;
            port.Parity = Parity.None;
            port.DataBits = 8;
            port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            port.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            port.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        }

        /*------------------------------------------------------
        Close the serial port and file.
        ------------------------------------------------------*/
        public void close()
        {
            if (port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.DataReceived -= port_DataReceived;
                port.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
                fs.Close();
            }
        }

        /*------------------------------------------------------
        Add the serial data received handler, open the file to
        log to, and open the serial port.
        ------------------------------------------------------*/
        public void open(string path)
        {
            if (!port.IsOpen)
            {
                fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                stream = new StreamWriter(fs);
                stream.AutoFlush = true;
                stream.WriteLine("Start");
                port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;
                port.Open();
            }
        }

        /*------------------------------------------------------
        Handler for the serial data events.
        ------------------------------------------------------*/
        void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string data = port.ReadExisting();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                    stream.Write(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code from the simple form I am using to open and close the connections:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace shell_log_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Shell.Shell port1;
        private Shell.Shell port2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            port2 = new Shell.Shell("COM5");
            port2.open("port2.log");
            port1 = new Shell.Shell("COM12");
            port1.open("port1.log");
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            port1.close();
            port2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Don't use static fields for instance items.

Comment: Yup that's correct, you will be left with the most recently updated port and streamwriter as both are static, they are created one per class and not one per instance.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. That corrected the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following:

```
static SerialPort port;
static FileStream fs;
static StreamWriter stream;
```

to:

```
private SerialPort port;
private FileStream fs;
private StreamWriter stream;
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. That corrected the problem.